# fs.writeFileSync method writing wrong to a text file

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs

I have a problem with my script related to writing to a text file.

The logic flow works as follows:
I read an entire unformatted text file with `fs.readFileSync` and pass all the read content to a variable of type string. After that I use the `.split` to break this text into several parts and keep each part of the broken text in an array. After that I use a for loop to go through this array and write to another text file, but here's the problem, I don't know if the information flow is too fast in the loop, which is sometimes written to this text file in a messy way, not respecting the order of the array being read.

Here is the code:

```
try{
    const data = fs.readFileSync('test_zpl.txt', 'utf8')
    txt = data.replace(/\s/g,"");
} catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
}

ArrayZPL = txt.split("+");

//Writting
for(i=0;i<ArrayZPL.length;i++){

    try{
        fs.writeFileSync('zpl_text.txt', ArrayZPL[i]);
    } catch (err){
        console.log(err);
    }

}

//Reading
try{
    const data = fs.readFileSync('zpl_text.txt', 'utf8')
    zpl = data;
} catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
}
```

Comment: in the times it fails, do you see errors logged to the console?

Comment: `which is sometimes written to this text file in a messy way, not respecting the order of the array being read.` indicates that the output is out of order. But `fs.writeFileSync('zpl_text.txt', ArrayZPL[i]);` would truncate the file if it exists, so it should always only contain one element of `ArrayZPL` so the code does not really match the described behavior. Is that really the actual code? If so could you clarify the behavior?

Comment: It's not a problem of "too fast" or "not respecting the order" because everything is synchronous. You are writing N times to `zpl_text.txt`, overwriting the same file each time. In the end, only the last iteration remains.

Comment: @JeremyKahan Doesn't show any error in the console.

Comment: @JeremyThille I think I understand what's going on. Grateful.

Comment: @t.niese Thank you very much for your attention. I think I solved my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`fs.writeFileSync` overwrites the file path passed as its first parameter. For a demonstration run the code below in node, type the contents of `test.txt` in the working directory on the console and repeat:

```
const fs = require("fs");
const path = require("path");
const filepath = path.resolve("./test.txt");

let string = "random-" + Math.random();
console.log( "writing %s to %s", string, filepath);
fs.writeFileSync( filepath, string);
```

To write the file in chunks you could create a writable stream and  write array entries in chunks using asynchronous code. To maintain synchronous code, join array entries and write the result:

```
fs.writeFileSync('zpl_text.txt', ArrayZPL.join("");
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I think I managed to solve the problem. Grateful